# How can I get a valid type object for generic constraints in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Im am trying to parse data provided in assemblies using reflection. In my scenario I am trying to figure out what kind of constraints a generic parameter might have. Here I run into a very strange problem: The generic constraint does return a crippled `Type` object.

Let me share this piece of code with you:

```
public class GenericTest
{

    public class MyGenericClass<T, U, V>
        where T : System.IO.StringReader
        where U : System.IO.StringWriter
        where V : SomeOtherClass<V>
    {
    }

    public class SomeOtherClass<X>
    {
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GenericTest));
        foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes()) {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(t.FullName);
            if (t.IsGenericType) {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("\tIsGeneric!");
                foreach (Type parm in t.GetGenericArguments()) {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("\tGeneric parameter: " + parm.Name);
                    Type[] constraints = parm.GetGenericParameterConstraints();
                    for (int i = 0; i < constraints.Length; i++) {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("\t\t constraint " + i + ": name = " + constraints[i].Name);
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("\t\t constraint " + i + ": fullname = " + constraints[i].FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The output is:

```
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.Program
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest+MyGenericClass`3
    IsGeneric!
    Generic parameter: T
        constraint 0: name = StringReader
        constraint 0: fullname = System.IO.StringReader
    Generic parameter: U
        constraint 0: name = StringWriter
        constraint 0: fullname = System.IO.StringWriter
    Generic parameter: V
        constraint 0: name = SomeOtherClass`1
        constraint 0: fullname =
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest+SomeOtherClass`1
    IsGeneric!
    Generic parameter: X
```

But that is not what I would expect. I would expect:

```
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.Program
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest+MyGenericClass`3
    IsGeneric!
    Generic parameter: T
        constraint 0: name = StringReader
        constraint 0: fullname = System.IO.StringReader
    Generic parameter: U
        constraint 0: name = StringWriter
        constraint 0: fullname = System.IO.StringWriter
    Generic parameter: V
        constraint 0: name = SomeOtherClass`1
        constraint 0: fullname = ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest+SomeOtherClass`1
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest+SomeOtherClass`1
    IsGeneric!
    Generic parameter: X
```

The point is that `FullName` returns `null` for constraints that refer to generic classes defined in the same assembly. This seems to be very strange: Why do I not get a valid `Type` object for `ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest.SomeOtherClass`? This way I have no way to tell what kind of class `SomeOtherClass` is! In this particular example `constraints[i].DeclaringType` would return a valid type object. But I encountered different situations where this is not the case. Therefor it seems that I do get a type object which is not considered tp be reasonable valid.

Q: Has anyone an idea why this is the case?

Q: How can I obtain the FQN for a type such as `SomeOtherClass`?

Q: For various reasons I can't use the latest version of .Net. Can anyone please verify if this problem is still encountered in the latest version of .Net?

Comment: Gergely Hamos brought me onto the right track. (Thank you!) You seem to be able to retrieve the correct type object by invoking `constraints[i].GetGenericTypeDefinition()`. As far as I can see this method will always return a valid `Type` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is the same in all .net versions.

I think the reason is written in the System.Type.FullName property definition in "Remarks" section (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx):

"If the current Type represents a type parameter of a generic type, or an array type, pointer type, or byref type based on a type parameter, this property returns null."

You can also find some explanation there.

If you want a FQN in this particular case (when FullName is null AND constraints[i].IsGenericTypeDefinition is true) then use this line instead

```
constraints[i].GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I haven't noticed that part of the text yet. Do you have any idea how I can find the correct Type object?

Comment: I edited the original answer, I think that solves your issue. Beware: GetGenericTypeDefinition() only works is "IsGenericTypeDefinition" prop is true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly I do not seem encounter the situation where `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` would return true, not for any constraint.

Comment: You are right, I tried it. But: in your case (example code above), IsConstructedGenericType property of constraints[i] returns true, and it seems that is enough for GetGenericTypeDefinition() to work.

edit: actually IsGenericType == true enough for GetGenericTypeDefinition() to work and return valid type object